# NoClassDefFoundError, but maven dependency exists in eclipse

Tags: java

I'm making some minecraft plugin that hooks into the JDA Discord API using Maven. The dependency loads but the class doesn't when I load it.

I've tried to make a separate project using default package and it works.
Now I moved the dependency from that bot project to my minecraft project, and the dependency successfully loads in the eclipse. However, when I ran my plugin, it shows me an error that the class doesn't exist.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/core/hooks/ListenerAdapte`

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.gmail.JyckoSianjaya.DonateCraft</groupId>
  <artifactId>DonateCraftV653</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
          <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
           <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
</repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.3_463</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>```
````

Comment: Try deleting the dependency jar files under /users/.m2/repository and download them again. Might be a corrupt jar.

Comment: Didn't work. @DeepakSharma I've deleted the folder and the jars.